# Does the javascript Window object not have local variables?

Tags: javascript

When I define a local variable under global namespace, it gets overwritten by an instance variable of the same name.

```
var outerVar;

outerVar = 'outerVar';
this.outerVar = 'thisOuterVar';
console.log(outerVar);            // thisOuterVar
```

However the same does not happen while inside a function.

```
var fun;

fun = function() {
  var innerVar;
  innerVar = 'innerVar';
  this.innerVar = 'thisInnerVar';
  return console.log(innerVar);      // innerVar
};

fun();
```

This code was run in Firebug.

```
this.constructor                  // Window { }
```

If I run the same code under node, where `this.constructor` is `[Function: Object]`, it returns 'outerVar' instead of 'thisOuterVar' which makes sense.

Why does it behave differently under Window?

Comment: Try `new fun();` and the result will be different (`this.innerVar` in your example without new is just the same as `window.innerVar`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run code in the browser from the global space like your first sample:

```
var outerVar;

outerVar = 'outerVar';
this.outerVar = 'thisOuterVar';
console.log(outerVar);
```

Then everything runs under the basic global space: `window` - this is basically the base scope of all environment in browser js.

so when you define value like `var outerVar` it's basically like `window.outerVar` or `this.outerVar` or `window['outerVar']`.

But if you run your code under anonymous function/object function like:

```
fun = function() {
  var innerVar;
  innerVar = 'innerVar';
  this.innerVar = 'thisInnerVar';
  return console.log(innerVar);      // innerVar
};
```

the `this` refer to the function(object) and the `var innerVar` refer to the scope of the function (like private var in basic oop class)
You can look at this like the `this.somevar` is **public** and `var othervar` is **private** - those are different things completely.

This is also answer your **node** question since in **node** everything runs under anonymous function "behind the scenes" - this is **commonjs** way - so in **node** it's basically the same as your anonymous function sample.

**Edit:**
As @bfavaretto comment me correctly - the `this.innerVar` is defined according to how you use it - meaning if you use it as regular function of course the `this` will be the window - hence global - if you make an object of it(like i thought - it will be define to the instance and be "**public**"):

```
function func(){
   alert(this);
}

func(); //alerts 'window'

var f = new func(); //alerts 'object'
```

Comment: Actually, the `this` inside the function refers to the global object (as the call is `fun()`, not `new fun()`).

Comment: This is what I said and meant - function(object)

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing! This is a good answer, but that part is confusing. You seem to mean that fun would be a constructor, and this would refer to the constructed instance (you even mention "public"), when that's not the case in the example from the OP (as the function is simply invoked, without the `new`  keyword)

Comment: It's the same thing - even if you define a "static" class which is an object that you don't have to run with `new` like `var SomeClass = {a:1,func: function(){var b;alert(this.a)}}` the variants inside `func` behaves the same as oop class in js - you can call without new like `SomeClass.func();` and still `var b` is like `private` and `this.a` is like public. same for if you making an instance from a function definition ("js class")

Comment: It's not the same! In your example, `this.a` *is* indeed a property of `SomeClass`; in the OP code, `this.innerVar` is **global**.

Comment: You are right ! but not completely - because this.innerVar is global only if you run the function as function like `fun();` but if you do `var f = new fun();` it is not `global` anymore - it will be the `object` - but you right - it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In the global namespace, 'a = 5;' is semantically equivalent to 'window.a = 5;', or 'this.a = 5;'

Answer (score 0):

You said, "When I define a **local variable** under global namespace...".  That's a contradiction in terms.  When you are in global scope there is no such thing as a 'local variable'.  As for what's happening inside your function, when you declare `var innerVar;` you are creating a variable that only exists in the scope of that function.  When you then modify `this.innerVar` inside the function, you're modifying (or declaring) the variable `innerVar` on whatever `this` happens to be at the time which, in this case, is `window` or, basically, global scope.